# django model form with bootstrap doesn't work

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a website using django but I have a problem with my modelforms. This is my working form code in my html-file:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Inschrijven!" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

If i use this code, everything works fine, when I fill in the form and press send, I can see the information from my admin-page.

I now tried to style my form using bootstrap:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">{{ field.label }}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{field.label}} ingeven">
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Inschrijven!" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

Now I have a nice bootstrap layout but if I fill in the form, I can't see the information at my admin-page. 
Does somebody know how I can fix this so I can keep the nice layout and still have my form to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you output Django HTML form, you will notice that it creates input elements with the following **ID** and **Name** attributes of the element.

Eg

```
class MyForm...
  name = ...
  age = ...
```

HTML

```
<input type='text' id='id_name' name='name' ...
<input type='text' id='id_age' name='age'...
```

To fix your issue, in your HTML add the following attribute to the HTML input field you're generating

`id="id_{{field.name}}" name="{{field.name}}"`

**Reasoning**:
When the form is submitted, the browser will send form encoded data in the form of `name=value` pair, which then arrives in form of dict in `request.POST` and when fed into Django form, it pre fills the form by matching the Django form attribute name to POST values.